# Black on Black QR Code , Monocrome Image QR code scan, Deep Scan Android

Tags: android

I am working on Android Project where I want to read a QR code on tyre, but it is black on black.
I the normal QR code scanner is not working.
**I got a similar app named scannect https://www.4jet.de/en/products/scannect-app**

Need help in searching for library to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to increase the contrast of the image before sending it to the barcode scanner software? Also it is better to use your own image rather than from an existing app to understand what difficulty you are having.

Comment: yes, we tried changing contrast and also tried connecting dotted line still no scan is detecting it. We need custom solution to read it.

Comment: Right now this is a `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic`, see [What can i ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Again better to show what you've tried with an image from your own app camera and code.

Comment: use the google's ML kit for that. reference : https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android

Comment: @AniruddhParihar thanks, it is working somehow but not seamlessly. may be I need to do some customization while scanning. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar hey Aniruddh can we connect over a call or chat

Comment: what is the Agenda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After R&D I have found that Google ML Kit Will help you on these types of BAR/QR Code Scanning.

For The Reference You can Follow These Linked Instructions.

[Building Barcode/QR code scanner for Android using Google ML Kit and CameraX](https://proandroiddev.com/building-barcode-qr-code-scanner-for-android-using-google-ml-kit-and-camerax-220b2852589e)

[Scan barcodes in Android using the ML Kit](https://medium.com/codex/scan-barcodes-in-android-using-the-ml-kit-30b2a03ccd50)

**Before you begin**

> This API requires Android API level 19 or above. Make sure that your
> app's build file uses a minSdkVersion value of 19 or higher.

1. In your project-level build.gradle file, make sure to include
   Google's Maven repository in both your buildscript and allprojects
   sections.
2. Add the dependencies for the ML Kit Android libraries to your
   module's app-level gradle file, which is usually app/build.gradle.
   Choose one of the following dependencies based on your needs:

**For bundling the model with your app:**

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  // Use this dependency to bundle the model with your app
  implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.0.2'
}
```

**For using the model in Google Play Services:**

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  // Use this dependency to use the dynamically downloaded model in Google Play Services
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:18.1.0'
}
```

3. **If you choose to use the model in Google Play Services**, you can configure your app to automatically download the model to the device
   after your app is installed from the Play Store. To do so, add the
   following declaration to your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application..>
<meta-data
          android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
          android:value="barcode" >
      <!-- To use multiple models: android:value="barcode,model2,model3" --> </application>
```

Best Of Luck in Advance.

Comment: Thanks for your input and efforts... Its working perfectly now...